# Access and read a char array as an int array

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I haven't found any solution among the many many threads about this.
My exact problem is:

I have an array of integers such as `unsigned int arr[2] = {0xFEBD1213, 0x1213FEBD};`

I would like to access those integers char by char, meaning that I need to read : `0x13, 0x12, 0xBD, 0xFE, 0xBD, 0xFE, 0x13, 0x12`.
I tried many, many things and I did not succeeded yet.

> Note : I would also like to do the opposite : having a char array with a size such as `size  %4 == 0`, and reading it as an integer array. E.g : `unsigned char arr[8] = {0x13, 0x12, 0xBD, 0xFE, 0xBD, 0xFE, 0x13, 0x12}` and read `0xFEBD1213, 0x1213FEBD`;

Is there any way of doing such a thing?

Minimal reproducible example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main(void){
  unsigned int arr[2] = {0xFEBD1213, 0x1213FEBD};
  unsigned char * ptr;
  ptr = *&arr; // I need a variable. Printing it doesn't matter to me. I am aware that there are easy solutions to print the right values there.
  for(int i = 0; i < 2 * 4; i++){
    printf("%x\n", *ptr);
    ptr = (ptr++);
  }
}
```

(I am aware that there are many cleaner way to code this, but I don't have the control over the type of the given array)

Comment: `ptr = (ptr + i);` ==> `ptr++;`

Comment: "I did not succeeded yet." What is the failure? You missed an important information.

Answer (score 2):

A simple shift and AND will work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main (void) {

    unsigned int arr[2] = {0xFEBD1213, 0x1213FEBD};

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        for (size_t j = 0; j< sizeof *arr; j++)
            printf ("0x%hhx\n", arr[i] >> (j * CHAR_BIT) & 0xff);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/arrbytes
0x13
0x12
0xbd
0xfe
0xbd
0xfe
0x13
0x12
```

To go from bytes to array just shift the opposite direction and OR.

Comment: That was not exactly what I needed. I needed a pointer variable from which I can iterate trough the array. Still, thanks for you answer. I posted my solution above.

Comment: Love it. Very elegant

Comment: @jijuji the problem with using a pointer is it does not take endianess into consideration. If you were to simply iterate over the bytes in `0xFEBD1213` on a little endian machine, your ordering would be `13`, `12`, `BD`, `FE` (where LSB is stored first in memory). When you use shifts, the compiler handles the byte-order appropriately. Try with `unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *)arr;` and then iterate with `for (; p != (unsigned char*)&arr[0] + sizeof arr; p++)` -- your byte order is reversed on LE.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That is exactly what I need, for it to keep the endianess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some kind of a parser:

```
void AccessAsCharArr(void *arr, size_t size);

int main()
{
    unsigned int arr[] = {0xFEBD1213, 0x1213FEBD, 0xFF000366};
    AccessAsCharArr(arr, sizeof(arr));
    return 0;
}

void AccessAsCharArr(void *arr, size_t size)
{
    unsigned char *ptr = arr;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        printf("%hhx ", *ptr);
        ptr++;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main(void){
  unsigned int arr[2] = {0xFEBD1213, 0x1213FEBD};
  unsigned char * ptr;
  ptr = &arr;
  for(int i = 0; i < 2 * 4; i++){
    printf("%x\n", *ptr);
    ptr = &*(ptr)+1;

  }

  unsigned char arr_c[8] = {0x13, 0x12, 0xBD, 0xFE, 0xBD, 0xFE, 0x13, 0x12};
  unsigned int * ptr_i;
  ptr_i = &arr_c;
  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
      printf("%x\n", *ptr_i);
      ptr_i = &*(ptr_i)+1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't post the code without an explanation where the error was.

Comment: `ptr = &*(ptr)+1;` is awful.